# How do I cite this page?

Tags: mla, citations

I am trying to cite this page in MLA: https://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/obscenity

Since it lists no authors, what should I put as the in-text citation. Should I use the Legal Information Institute or should I omit an author and just use Obscenity?

Also, this is what my works cited citation looks like. Is this correct?

```
"Obscenity." Obscenity. Legal Information Institute, n.d. Web. Apr. 2015.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In MLA citation, the author is put before the website.

```
Lastname, Firstname. "Title." Website Title (Italics). Publisher, Date Month Year of publication. Web. Date month year of access.
```

If there is no author, just omit the author and begin the citation with `"Title.`